# Selenium Webdriver stuck at Cloadflare DDos Protection. How to bypass manually?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to build a project using selenium webdriver, I need to get into a website that has Cloudflare enabled. I would like to bypass it manually by myself. However, the cloudflare page keeps reloading the Ray ID and doesn't let me verify. What should I do?

This is code snippet:

```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import undetected_chromedriver as uc

options = Options()
options.add_argument("ignore-certificate-errors")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
browser = uc.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install(), chrome_options=options)

browser.get(BASE_URL + '/our-selection/')
input('Continue?')
```

> Checking your browser before accessing website. This process is
> automatic. Your browser will redirect to your requested content
> shortly.
>
> Please allow up to 5 seconds…
>
> DDoS protection by Cloudflare

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A friend of mine suggested to go to a normal (chrome or firefox) browser, open the website and complete the cloudflare step manually then load the cookies of that browser in my python code. It worked & I didn't need selenium at all.

Here is a sample code:

```
import requests
import browser_cookie3

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:92.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/92.0',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
    'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
    'TE': 'trailers',
}

def getResponse(url):
    while True:
        cookies = browser_cookie3.firefox(domain_name='WEBSITE-DOMAIN')
        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, cookies=cookies)
        time.sleep(1)
        if response.status_code == 403:
            input(f'Cloudflare Detected: Please verify on firefox then press ENTER!')
        elif response.status_code == 200:
            print(f'Response 200 {url}')
            return response
        elif response.status_code == 404:
            return 404
```

So you use `getResponse(URL)` instead of `requests.get(URL)`. The function will detect if Cloudflare blocks you, if so it will ask you to finish the task in browser then press enter in terminal for the code to continue running.

I know it is not 100% practical but for small work I think it is a perfect.

For cookies:

```
cookies = browser_cookie3.firefox(domain_name='WEBSITE-DOMAIN')
```

if you prefer to use chrome, change `firefox` to `chrome`

Hopefully this answer works for you too!